# Display file name of all files with certain extension

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zenity

What I want is for the user to select a file from anywhere using zenity, and the script will detect the file extension, for example (.tar.gz) or (.zip), and perform actions on them accordingly. Here's an example.

```
#! /bin/bash

FILE=$(zenity --file-selection --title="Select a file to check")
echo "File: $FILE"

if [ "$FILE" = "*.zip" ] 
then
    echo "File that is a .zip found"
    FILENAMENOEXT="${FILE%.*}"
    echo "Filename with extention $FILENAMENOEXT"
    #Perform xx action to $FILE if it is a zip

elif [ "$FILE" = "*.tar.gz" ]
then
echo "File is a .tar.gz found"
FILENAMENOEXT="${FILE%.tar.*}"
echo "Filename with extention $FILENAMENOEXT"
#Perform xx action to $FILE if it is a t.tar.gz

else
    echo "File is neither .zip nor .tar.gz"
fi

echo "test $FILENAMENOEXT"
```

Comment: Side note: if you want your tool to recognize files by their content (e.g. because some files are `.tar.gz` while others are `.tgz`), the `file` util might come in handy. E.g. `file -b --mime-type something.tar.gz` would give you `application/gzip`.

Comment: what you want to perform after getting .zip and .tar.gz files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost correct.

You need to use `[[` to do pattern matching and quotes disable pattern matching.

So instead of `[ "$FILE" = "*.zip" ]` you want `[[ "$FILE" = *".zip" ]]` and instead of `[ "$FILE" = "*.tar.gz" ]` you want `[[ "$FILE" = *".tar.gz" ]]`.

You could also use a `case` statement instead of `if`/`elif`.

```
case "$FILE" in
*.zip)
    echo "File that is a .zip found"
    ;;
*.tar.gz)
    echo "File is a .tar.gz found"
    ;;
*)
    echo "File is neither .zip nor .tar.gz"
    ;;
esac
```